# UltimateRecycleView : SetLoadMoreView is Not Working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working with Android and UltimateRecycleView. I manage to make the ultimaterecycleview working, but when I tried to use the load more functionality, the bottom progress bar is not showing (although the data is loaded). Anyone has experienced this problem? Can you please help me to find out what is wrong?

Here is the code :

--- Adapter ---

```
public class ListPendingAdapter extends UltimateViewAdapter<ListPendingAdapter.PendingViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Queue> queues;

    public ListPendingAdapter(Context context, List<Queue> queues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.queues = queues;
    }

    @Override
    public PendingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pending_list, parent, false);
        PendingViewHolder vh = new PendingViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PendingViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView nodata = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        if(queues.size() <= 0){
            nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            User user = new User(queues.get(position).getQueuer());

            if (user.getProfilePicture() == null) {
                holder.photo.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_photo));
            } else {
                ImageUtil.setParseFileImageToView(context, user.getProfilePicture(), holder.photo);
            }

            holder.name.setText(user.getFullname());
            holder.totalPerson.setText(Integer.toString(queues.get(position).getTotalPax()));
            holder.timeQueue.setText(DateUtil.formatDateIntoTimeString(queues.get(position).getCreatedAt()));
            attachButtonClickListener(holder.accept, true, position, holder.parent);
            attachButtonClickListener(holder.reject, false, position, holder.parent);

            CustomerUtil.attachUsernameListener((Activity) context, holder.name, queues.get(position));
            CustomerUtil.attachProfpicListener((Activity) context, holder.photo, queues.get(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size = (queues == null ? 0 : queues.size());
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public PendingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pending_list, viewGroup, false);
        PendingViewHolder vh = new PendingViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public PendingViewHolder getViewHolder(View view) {
        return new PendingViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_bottom_progressbar, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public long generateHeaderId(int position) {
        if (getItem(position).get("objectId").toString().length() > 0)
            return (getItem(position).get("objectId").toString()).charAt(0);
        else return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAdapterItemCount() {
        int size = (queues == null ? 0 : queues.size());
        return size;
    }

    public Queue getItem(int position) {
        if (customHeaderView != null)
            position--;
        if (position < queues.size())
            return queues.get(position);
        else return null;
    }

    private void attachButtonClickListener(Button button, final boolean isAccept, final int position, final View parent){

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callPendingProcess(isAccept, position, parent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void callPendingProcess(final boolean isAccept, final int position, final View parent){
        ProcessPending processPending = new ProcessPending(context, this, isAccept, position, parent);
        processPending.execute();
    }

    public List<Queue> getDataset(){
        return queues;
    }

    public static class PendingViewHolder extends UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder {
        public CircleImageView photo;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView totalPerson;
        public TextView timeQueue;
        public Button accept;
        public Button reject;

        public View parent;

        public PendingViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            parent = v;

            photo = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
            totalPerson = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.total_cust);
            timeQueue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_queue);
            accept = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.accept_btn);
            reject = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.reject_btn);
        }
    }
}
```

--- Async Task (where I set the adapter to listview) ---

```
public class LoadPendingCustomer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Queue>> {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private View view;

    private View layout;
    private int skipCount;
    private boolean isLoadMore;

    public LoadPendingCustomer(Context context, View layout, int skipCount, boolean isLoadMore) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;

        this.layout = layout;
        this.skipCount = skipCount;
        this.isLoadMore = isLoadMore;

        this.pb = (ProgressBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.pending_progress);
        this.view = layout.findViewById(R.id.pending_list_container);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(!isLoadMore) {
            ProgressUtil.showProgress(true, view, pb, context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Queue> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        List<Queue> queues = null;

        try {
            List<String> statuses = new ArrayList<String>();
            statuses.add(Queue.STATUS_PENDING_APPROVAL);

            queues = QueueDao.getCustomersBasedOnStatus(statuses, skipCount);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.w(MainActivity.TAG, "Error while retrieving pending queues", e);
        }

        return queues;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Queue> results) {
        TextView nodata = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        if(results == null){
            nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            if (results.size() <= 0) {
                if(!isLoadMore) {
                    nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                UltimateRecyclerView queueList = (UltimateRecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pendinglist);

                if(!isLoadMore || queueList.getAdapter() == null){
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);

                    ListPendingAdapter listPendingAdapter = new ListPendingAdapter(context, results);

                    queueList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    queueList.setAdapter(listPendingAdapter);
                } else {
                    ListPendingAdapter listPendingAdapter = (ListPendingAdapter) queueList.getAdapter();
                    listPendingAdapter.getDataset().addAll(results);
                    listPendingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                setLoadMore(queueList);
            }
        }

        if(!isLoadMore) {
            ProgressUtil.showProgress(false, view, pb, context);
        }
    }

    private void setLoadMore(final UltimateRecyclerView queueList){
        queueList.reenableLoadmore();
        queueList.setLoadMoreView(R.layout.custom_bottom_progressbar);

        queueList.setOnLoadMoreListener(new UltimateRecyclerView.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadMore(int i, int i1) {
                LoadPendingCustomer loadPendingCustomer = new LoadPendingCustomer(context, layout, skipCount + 10, true);
                loadPendingCustomer.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

--- fragment xml ---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".fragments.QueueFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pending_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pending_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nodata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/nodata"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/pending_swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/pendinglist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

--- custom_bottom_progressbar.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottomPB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_progress_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance...